# Does StackExchange.Redis has E-Tag support?

Tags: .net, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis, etag

We are using StackExchange.Redis to connect to Redis cache. But instead to downloading the full object every time, we are looking for an option if we can keep a local copy of object with e-Tag attached to it and download from Redis server only when the object changed in the Redis store. Which means every time there is a need to access this cached object, will make a request to Redis server with ETag and it will return object only when e-Tag is different else it will respond back with 304 in which case will pick the object from local copy.
I could not find this functionality in StackExchange.Redis client, so just wanted to confirm if such capability is supported by StackExchange.Redis out of the box or if there is any other redis client library available which support such functionality?